# Dataflow unable to GET a reference to BigQuery tables when too many cores or more than one machine

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My streaming Dataflow pipeline is supposed to read analytics hits from Pub/Sub and write them to BigQuery. If I use too many machines, or they're too big, it throws rate limit errors when getting a reference to the tables, more precisely when executing _get_or_create_table.

The rate limit that is reached seems to be one of [these](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#all_api_requests): 100 API requests per second per user, 300 concurrent API requests per user.

It is not blocking the pipeline (rows get written after some point), but I have the feeling it blocks some of the threads and prevents me from fully taking advantage of the parallelization. Switching from one machine with 4 CPUs to 5 with each 8 CPUs brought no improvement to the latency (in fact it got worse).

How can I avoid this error, and have a high number of machines write to BQ ?

Here's the log from the Dataflow monitoring interface. It is appearing regularly when I launch the pipeline:

```
...
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py", line 1087, in get_or_create_table
    found_table = self._get_table(project_id, dataset_id, table_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 184, in wrapper
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py", line 925, in _get_table
    response = self.client.tables.Get(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/internal/clients/bigquery/bigquery_v2_client.py", line 611, in Get
    config, request, global_params=global_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 722, in _RunMethod
    return self.ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 728, in ProcessHttpResponse
    self.__ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 599, in __ProcessHttpResponse
    http_response, method_config=method_config, request=request)

HttpForbiddenError: HttpError accessing <https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<project_id>/datasets/<dataset_id>/tables/<table_id>?alt=json>: response: <{'status': '403', 'content-length': '577', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'expires': 'Sun, 25 Nov 2018 14:36:24 GMT', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin', 'server': 'GSE', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 'date': 'Sun, 25 Nov 2018 14:36:24 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "rateLimitExceeded",
    "message": "Exceeded rate limits: Your user_method exceeded quota for api requests per user per method. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "helix_api.method_request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Exceeded rate limits: Your user_method exceeded quota for api requests per user per method. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors"
```

Here's the code of the pipeline. I cut pretty much everything in it to see if this still happens:

```
p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

msgs = p | 'Read' >> beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub(
    topic='projects/{project}/topics/{topic}'.format(
        project=args.project, topic=args.hits_topic),
    id_label='hit_id',
    timestamp_attribute='time')

lines = msgs | beam.Map(lambda x: {'content': x})

(lines
    | 'WriteToBQ' >> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(args.table,
                                                          dataset=args.dataset,
                                                          project=args.project))
```

Comment: Can you share your Dataflow code?

Comment: Sure, just added this

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading to the latest `apache_beam` library (2.12.0 as of writing). https://github.com/apache/beam/commit/932e802279a2daa0ff7797a8fc81e952a4e4f252 introduced caching of tables that would otherwise trigger the rate limits you likely encountered in an older version of this library.